# Block users in online Android app

Tags: android, security

I'm developing a mobile online Android game. Some of users violate game rules and I need to block them and restrict using some functions in the app.
What parameters I should to retrieve to identify users devices and then add into DB as blocked? What methods do you use to implement this functionality in your projects?

**Update.**
Now I already use IP address and ANDROID_ID, but users can change these parameters easily

**Update 2.**
I already use my own users system for identifying users. User need to create account using email. But the problem is bad users make new accounts and keep violating game rules. So the purpose is to block these users devices to prevent them even to create new account using that blocked device.

Comment: IP is a horrible one to use.  You're probably blocking entire towers.

Comment: Simple answer is don't try. There's always a way around it. And there's people who can use an android emulator like GenyMotion and still violate game rules. Maybe you can attempt to prevent users from violating game rules (for example, packet sniffing/packet replay).

Comment: Maybe this link would help? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Answer (score 0):

Imei perhaps. Good enough for me lol

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_ID is not static nor unique, it can change with factory reset, rooted device, if user changes account. Refer to Google documents for more info. And it's not recommended to get Hardware id. If you still want get unique id, you can get wifi or bluetooth adapter's mac address. 
For 6+ you can't use The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() method and the BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress() method will both return 02:00:00:00:00:00.. But there are still ways to get them. You can look for it too. I don't remember how it was done but i had done it but it's not recommended by Google to get Hardware ids.

[Google Documentation for Unique Ids](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html)